# null pointer exception android studio

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null

this is what I am trying to do. First, get the current text size from a radio button, and then set the text size of a text view to that value. however, when I try I always get a "null pointer exception" error. i have researched this and not found an answer that fixes my problem. The radio button is rb1 and the textview is sampleText.

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

RadioButton rb1;
RadioButton rb2;
RadioButton rb3;
RadioGroup ans;
TextView sampleT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    ans= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answers);
    rb1= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    rb2= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    rb3= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    sampleT= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleText);

     float default_font_size=rb1.getTextSize(); //this is the line with error
     sampleT.setTextSize(default_font_size);

    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
06-11 14:37:31.809  15625-15625/com.nick.simplequiz            E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.simplequiz/com.nick.simplequiz.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nick.simplequiz.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
```

settings.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Answer Choice Text Size"
        android:id="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:progress="50"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Either `rb1` or `sampleText` is `null`. Make sure you initialize these.

Comment: yes i checked and both are initialized before this

Comment: Are you sure? Did you check the values at runtime, either by logging them or using the debug mode?

Comment: float default_font_size=rb1.getTextSize(); is line 32

Comment: Yes, see my previous comment

Comment: Ummm, the radio buttons seem rather absent from the xml file ...

Comment: yes they are in a different xml file. so the components i am accessing can only be from the current layout and not a different one?

Comment: Exactly! See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're going for here but

```
rb1= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
```

returns `null` so you get a `NPE` when you run

```
 float default_font_size=rb1.getTextSize();
```

because `rb1` is `null` since it isn't in the xml you inflate with

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

You have to `inflate` a `layout` either with

```
`setContentView(R.layout.yourXML);
```

or with an [inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). Your `View`s exist within your `layout` so they return `null` if not within a `layout` you have inflated

Comment: ok i see what you are saying. ill have to figure out another way to do what im trying to do. thanks for helping me

Comment: You can't without `inflating` the xml file they are in. I'm not sure why you are trying to do it this way but you can't

Comment: what i'm really trying to do it change the text size of text that is used in my app but it is in a different layout. i want to be able to change it from a settings layout. there must be a simpler way

Comment: @ez4nick You can change to a `SettingsActivity`, make it a dialog or whatever so the user doesn't feel as though they have left the current screen, and save the value in `SharedPreferences` then read that value to set the text size